# Linux, SSD, TRIM - Not working? (hdparm, Samsung)

Tags: linux, ssd, fedora, luks, samsung-ssd

MY SSD is working but TRIM may not be.

I'm running Fedora 36 with BTRFS. I installed a *Samsung SSD 980 PRO* 2TB SSD firmware version *5B2QGXA7* as a secondary drive that does not auto mount, as intended. I have the drive set as LUKS Encrypted. Everything appears to work, unlock, mount, unmount, lock, as intended.

**My concern revolves around TRIM**.

Running fstrim produces:

> the discard operation is not supported

In my efforts to make sure *discards* is enabled everywhere I checked to make sure it was supported with **hdparm**. This really confused me!

```
sudo hdparm -I /dev/nvme0n1

/dev/nvme0n1:
```

Nothing?

```
sudo hdparm -i /dev/nvme0n1

/dev/nvme0n1:
 HDIO_GET_IDENTITY failed: Inappropriate ioctl for device
```

and

```
sudo hdparm /dev/nvme0n1

/dev/nvme0n1:
 readonly      =  0 (off)
 readahead     = 256 (on)
 geometry      = 1907729/64/32, sectors = 3907029168, start = 0
```

So now I'm wondering if this is a **Samsung issue**?

I'm not sure where to go from here?

### EDIT

I've been told that **hdparm** does not support NVME, only SATA.

Comment: No expert on this. Does this help / answer the question: https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/Dm-crypt/Specialties#Discard/TRIM_support_for_solid_state_drives_(SSD)

Comment: @Joep van Steen - Thanks for the thought. I've tried variants of that without sucess, that's why I went directly to HDPARM to verify the SSD supports TRIM and got weird results.

Comment: Probably not help, but I would run `smartctl -x /dev/nvme0n1` and see what it says.

Comment: @Bib - Good thought, everything looks normal, no errors. Nothing about TRIM.

Answer (score 1):

I have it working now. It turns out I left off a key piece of information I didn't know was pertinent. So for anyone else:

I was using the GUI *gnome-disk-utility* for unlocking and mounting the encrypted partition.

I was unable to to find a direct gnome-disk-utility option to make it work. **However**:

Manually unlocking from the command line **once** with:

```
sudo cryptsetup luksOpen --allow-discards --persistent /dev/nvme0n1p1 ssd-1_partition
```

Resolved the issue.

The **--persistent** option wrote the *--allow-discards* into the LUKS2 header metadata. Now *gnome-disk-utility* simply works and TRIM is enabled.

See [ArchLinux TRIM Support](https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/Dm-crypt/Specialties#Discard/TRIM_support_for_solid_state_drives_(SSD))

### How to test if TRIM is enabled:

```
sudo lsblk --discard   
NAME                                           DISC-ALN DISC-GRAN DISC-MAX DISC-ZERO
     nvme0n1                                        0    512B      2T       0
     └─nvme0n1p1                                    0    512B      2T       0 
       └─luks-ffb768b8-144c-4250-8eb7-17f11cc7367c  0    512B      2T       0
```

The **third** entry will be missing or zeros if TRIM is not enabled.